# Recursively find json by key && value and update in-place

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-json

I'm trying to find how I can search for AND update a value inside an array of JSON objects, where the key and value I'm looking for, can be at any different levels.

I've created a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Prc5sAfO) with some sample data.
To make it easier to read the JSON data, here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/CelsoSantos/6e9d0019f579e310d12f3801a90a4fce#file-dbfiddle-sample-data.json) with a pretty format.

So, let's take this in parts:

- ### What am I trying to achieve?

  I'm trying to replace the value of `url` in the `media_items` table, and the values of `url` and `originalUrl` in the `documents_revisions` table with new values, for a server migration. `url` will point to my server and `original_url` will point to an AWS S3 bucket.

Let's look at this `media_item` entry example:

```json
// media_item simplified example...
{
  "key": "2021/1/29/04aaf6f1-bf13-4918-a062-355bdf192d2f.jpeg",
  "url": "https://my.old.url/api/v1/images/4166289-f-542-d-445-b-a-0-d-1-ec-7916-c-0748-e.jpeg?id=MQkvMjAyMi8wMS8yMC80MTY2Mjg5Zi01NDJkLTQ0NWItYTBkMS1lYzc5MTZjMDc0OGUuanBlZwk4OTY%3D",
}
```

This `key` is the actual path/URL to the resource on my server and s3 bucket, and `url` allows me to get the "original" value, which is then used in the documents/revisions in `document_revisions`. The "original" `url` also contains a base64 encoded `id` param, which is just the `key` as a base64 string.

- ### How am I trying to do it?

The current approach I'm taking, has me:

1. read the values of `url` and `key` from the `media_items` table (in the fiddle) into a `item record` variable (which then get iterated upon).
2. I then load the `url` value into a `old_url` variable (to re-use it during "searches")

```sql
old_url := "https://my.old.url/api/v1/images/4166289-f-542-d-445-b-a-0-d-1-ec-7916-c-0748-e.jpeg?id=MQkvMjAyMi8wMS8yMC80MTY2Mjg5Zi01NDJkLTQ0NWItYTBkMS1lYzc5MTZjMDc0OGUuanBlZwk4OTY%3D"
```

3. create a `new_url` variable with the new value, which is something like:

```sql
new_url := CONCAT('https://my.new.url', '/', '"' , item.key, '"')

-- output: https://my.new.url/2021/1/29/04aaf6f1-bf13-4918-a062-355bdf192d2f.jpeg
```

4. With these variables, I'll update the `media_items.asset->'url'` entry to `new_url` **AND** look for the value of `old_url` in **ALL** revisions in `document_revisions`:

```sql
do $$
-- (...)

    -- Update the media_items asset->'url'
    UPDATE media_items mle
    SET asset = REPLACE(
      (mle.asset)::TEXT,
      CONCAT('"url": ', old_url
      CONCAT('"url": ', '"', new_url, '"')
    )::JSONB;
    
    -- Update the document_revisions 
    UPDATE document_revisions dr
    SET data = REPLACE(
        (dr.data)::TEXT,
        CONCAT('"url": ', old_url),
        CONCAT('"url": ', '"', new_url, '"')
    )::JSONB;

    UPDATE document_revisions dr
    SET data = REPLACE(
        (dr.data)::TEXT,
        CONCAT('"originalUrl": ', old_url),
        CONCAT('"originalUrl": ', '"', new_url, '"')
    )::JSONB;

-- (...)
end; $$;
```

Now, as you can see, this is not a very good/performant approach as I'm relying on parsing JSON to text, finding a certain substring (which represents a JSON `key: value`) and then replacing it with the new value.

It is, however, fairly simple to target the `url` key in the `media_items` table, so I could simply change to a more directed approach:

```sql
-- A much better solution to the media_items update above
UPDATE
  media_items mle
SET 
  asset = JSONB_SET(asset, '{url}', CONCAT('"', new_url, '"')::JSONB)
WHERE
  item.id = mle.id;
```

On the other hand, the same is **NOT** true for the revisions in `document_revisions`, as the `url` and `originalUrl` can be at any depth level of json objects in the `document_revisions.data->'data'->'content'` item array (look at the sample data in the gist, it's pretty complete even though text components have been severely shrunk of text for the sake of readability). I'm not sure how to get the array index of the json object to update and update it's property/key

I did find a couple possible solutions that used jsonb operators, but I'm not sure how to use them to achieve my intended result:

```sql
-- This will return all the revisions which contain an object, at any depth, whose key is `url`.
SELECT dr.*
FROM   document_revisions dr
WHERE  (dr.data->'content')::jsonb @? 'strict $.** ? (exists (@."url"))';

-- This will return all the revisions that contain an json value equal to the defined url
SELECT dr.*
FROM   document_revisions dr
WHERE  (dr.data->'content')::JSONB @? 'strict $.** ? (@ == "https://my.old.url/api/v1/images/covid-19-m-rna-vaccines.png?id=MQkvMjAyMS82LzEvZWI2YzQwZjItMjYzMS00MTY4LWFhZGQtNjZjMmVkOTg5ZDQ2LnBuZwk4MTQ=")';
```

I tried combining the two options (meaning, find by key AND value) with something to the likes of the next example, but that doesn't work, nor have I found an iteration of this that works:

```sql
SELECT dr.*
FROM   document_revisions dr
WHERE  (dr.data->'content')::jsonb @? 'strict $.** ? (exists (@."url") && @ == "https://server.livingdocs.io/api/v1/images/a.jpg?id=MQkvMjAyMC8xMS8yNS9mNjgyN2E5ZC0xZjViLTQzZGUtOGNiNy1iY2RhNjgyYTFhMjMuanBlZwk4OTY=")';
```

The only simple way I've found so far to do this is by doing string replacements, but this is slow and ineffective. It took me over 2 hours to update 150 media assets, which can then correspond to any amount of revisions between 1 and N.
I currently have 6k assets and 23k revisions, where each revision can use N assets, so it's not being good...

Now, my questions are:

- Is there a way to update in-place, a given json key/property at any index and level of an array?
- Is there a way to speed up the string replacement?
- How would you do this? I've tried creating temporary tables, unlogged tables, creating unindexed copies of the tables, and nothing works... Help please?

Thanks

---

### EDIT:

Based on @Ajax1234 answer (thank you) the final solution ended up being a set of functions that are available in [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/https://dbfiddle.uk/C96SJeAz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible method for handling arbitrarily nested data is to find all the JSON paths in `document_revisions.data` that point to the value of `url` or `originalUrl` keys and then use a function with a `loop` to repeatedly update `document_revisions` in place.

First, update `media_items`:

```
update media_items set asset = asset || jsonb_build_object('new_url', 'https://my.new.url/'||((asset -> 'key')#>>'{}'));
```

Then, create a `cte` that will return all paths for every value in each `data`:

```sql
create or replace function document_paths() returns table(id text, path text, arr_js jsonb, obj_js jsonb)
language sql
as $$
  with recursive cte(id, path, arr_js, obj_js) as (
     select d.id, '', case when jsonb_typeof(d.data) = 'array' then d.data 
                  else '[null]'::jsonb end, 
            case when jsonb_typeof(d.data) = 'object' then d.data 
              else '{"null":null}'::jsonb end
     from document_revisions d
     union all
     select c.id, c.path ||(case when c.path != '' then ',' else '' end)||(case when arr_js.elem#>>'{}' is null then obj_js.key else arr_js.i::text end), 
        case when arr_js.elem#>>'{}' is null then 
           (case when jsonb_typeof(obj_js.value) = 'array' then obj_js.value 
                 else '[null]'::jsonb end) else 
                 (case when jsonb_typeof(arr_js.elem) = 'object' then '[null]'::jsonb when jsonb_typeof(arr_js.elem) = 'array' then arr_js.elem else '[]'::jsonb end) end,
         case when obj_js.value#>>'{}' is null then 
           (case when jsonb_typeof(arr_js.elem) = 'object' then arr_js.elem 
                 else '{"null":null}'::jsonb end) else 
                 (case when jsonb_typeof(obj_js.value) = 'object' then obj_js.value 
                       else (case when jsonb_typeof(obj_js.value) = 'array' then '{"null":null}'::jsonb 
                               else '{}'::jsonb end) end) end
     from cte c 
     cross join lateral (select row_number() over (order by 1) - 1 i, t.value elem 
                 from jsonb_array_elements(c.arr_js) t) arr_js 
     cross join jsonb_each(c.obj_js) obj_js
  )
  select * from cte
$$
```

Lastly, create a function (this can also be done in a procedure) to perform the updates:

```sql
create or replace function run_updates()
  returns void as
$body$
declare
    c record;
begin
  for c in select * from document_paths() -- loop over each path
  loop
    if c.obj_js = '{}'::jsonb and (c.path ~ 'url' or c.path ~ 'originalUrl') then -- check if path is pointing to a url or originalUrl
      -- perform update
      update document_revisions set data = jsonb_set(data, ('{'||c.path||'}')::text[], m.asset -> 'new_url') 
      from media_items m where document_revisions.id = c.id and 
        ((data::jsonb#>('{'||c.path||'}')::text[])#>>'{}') like ((m.asset -> 'url')#>>'{}')||'%';
    end if;
  end loop;
end
$body$
language plpgsql
```

Explanation of `update` query:

```sql
update document_revisions set data = jsonb_set(data, ('{'||c.path||'}')::text[], 
      m.asset -> 'new_url') -- using the path to the url in the document, update the url with the new_url in media_items
from media_items m -- join previously updated media_items to document_revisions
-- if there is a basic substring match (you might want to change the exact match conditions later on) between the old_url in media_values and the url found in document_revisions via the path
-- then perform the update above
where document_revisions.id = c.id and 
        ((data::jsonb#>('{'||c.path||'}')::text[])#>>'{}') like ((m.asset -> 'url')#>>'{}')||'%'
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pyat6qMW)

---

A more memory efficient approach can be to find all `url` and `originalUrl`s from `document_revisions` and then perform an in-place series of updates in a function. In this way, `data` is not being repeatedly loaded into memory all at once, as it is for the solution above.

First, update `media_items`:

```
update media_items set asset = asset || jsonb_build_object('new_url', 
   'https://my.new.url/'||((asset -> 'key')#>>'{}'));
```

Then, using a procedure to find all `url`s in `document_revisions` and then performing the replacements:

```sql
create or replace function run_updates()
  returns void as
$body$
declare
    c record;
begin
  for c in (select t.id, url from (select d.id, 
        regexp_matches(d.data::text, '(?:(?<=url"\:)(?:\s+)*"([^"]+))|(?:(?<=Url"\:)(?:\s+)*"([^"]+))', 'g') v 
      from document_revisions d) t cross join unnest(t.v) url
      where url is not null)
  loop
     update document_revisions set data = replace(data::text, c.url, ((m.asset -> 'new_url')#>>'{}'))::jsonb from media_items m where document_revisions.id = c.id and 
        c.url like ((m.asset -> 'url')#>>'{}')||'%';
  end loop;
end
$body$
language plpgsql
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iAv6yKa6)

As with the previous solutions, a replacement of `url` or `originalUrl` with `media_items.new_url` only occurs when the latter matches as a substring of the former:

```
c.url like ((m.asset -> 'url')#>>'{}')||'%'
```

Comment: :clap: I'm not going to lie.. I'm impressed (though that can easily be attributed to my unfamiliarity with Postgresql and JSON data). However, I seem to be hitting some issue with the `document_paths()` CTE as I'm getting an error output: 

`SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: cannot extract elements from a scalar
  Where: SQL function "document_paths" statement 1`

Would you happen to know why that is? Seems like we're getting some form of scalar where we should be finding an array, if I understand this correctly.

Comment: @Zed_Blade Thank you. I updated `document_paths()` to ensure that scalars in `arrays` are accounted for (originally, it assumed that all array elements were either objects or arrays themselves). Please let me know how this works for you.

Comment: Hello @Ajax1234, thanks for the edit, now it no longer errors.. But seems like I ran into another issue which I had already encountered when doing the "dumb" string search/replace approach: The `documents_path()` execution seems to make the disk size grow off-the charts (from less than 600MB to more than 90GB when I stopped the process).

Should I be doing this in temporary tables maybe? Disable indexing?

Comment: @Zed_Blade Sorry for delayed response. I added a new solution which should be significantly more memory efficient. In brief, it uses `regexp_match` and replacements in a procedure, updating `document_revisions` in place. This way, `document_revisions.data` is not being continuously loaded into memory, as it is in the recursive `cte` from the prior solution.

Comment: my turn to apologise for the late reply. I think we're nearly almost there. There is one situation which I thought a simple `LIKE` would solve but it doesn't:
If a url is like `https://server.example.io/api/v1/images/firstorder.jpg?id=MQk...TgxNA%3D%3D&rect=599%2C108%2C810%2C500&auto=format`, where it contains some params after "the base" the `c.url like ((m.asset -> 'url')#>>'{}')||'%'` seems to fail the match. Is that due to the `%` char? URLs like `https://server.example.io/api/v1/images/firstorder.jpg?id=MQk...TgxNA%3D%3D` work fine, but the ones with params fail :(

Comment: BTW, the CTE version works a lot better (both memory and disk) if I iterate per each document and keep it short. However, it also seems to suffer from this same issue as above

Comment: @Zed_Blade The `like` with the trailing `%` is a direct substring match, looking from the beginning (i.e `str.startswith` in Python). Depending on the characters in your URLs, it is certainly possible `%` is causing difficulties. Instead, of `like`, you can use the operator `~`: `c.url ~ ((m.asset -> 'url')#>>'{}')`; `((data::jsonb#>('{'||c.path||'}')::text[])#>>'{}') ~ ((m.asset -> 'url')#>>'{}')`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I had (and have again) tried that, even in the fiddle that solution somehow seems to be worse as either only `originalUrl` is updated or `url` ends up losing whatever params it had... Anyway, I'm going to accept your answer and probably open another question related to the the `like` vs `~`. Thanks a lot for the help and availability to reply

Comment: @Zed_Blade Perhaps you could match on just the URL domains, and ignore the parameters? That would be considerably more robust, but I am not entirely sure if it would be compatible with your overall problem scenario.

Comment: so, just to conclude, the issue was the dataset I had and also quite a bit of a PICNIC :)

I did have to modify the last function a little bit to better handle my specific use-case, but it works flawlessly! Thanks again. I owe you a six pack. In case you're interested, the final solution ended up something like the fiddle at the edited original question